# Embed interactive shell (VTE) in a PyGtk GUI to manipulate its own widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, terminal-emulator

I am planning to do the folliwing:

Create a PyGtk GUI (hardcoded, no Glade) with some widgets, and at the bottom of the screen put some sort of VTE (Virtual Terminal Emulator) from where I could manipulate the widgets, for example changing their attributes and calling their methods from the commandline.

The result would be similar to using AutoCAD's commands, only that I would be acting upon the GUI objects.

I have already found very few things about `gtk.VteTerminal` widget, but not only could not find a working example or make one myself, it also seem to be a system terminal, not a "current session" python terminal where I could run python commands and access GUI objects.

Any suggestion?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want exists already: [GtkParasite](https://chipx86.github.io/gtkparasite/). It's meant for debugging, but I'm sure if you wanted it to actually be a part of your application, you could adapt it.

Comment: I'll have to take some time to check it out, but thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but I had a similar problem.
Look here
[Virtual Terminal Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804455/how-to-send-commands-to-pygobject-virtual-terminal/11810239#11810239)

It's an option if you decide to do something different than what you might have already done.

Comment: Actually I want a Python terminal of the current section, with the gtk objects accessible for CLI interaction, not a linux terminal inside a GTK environment... But thanks anyway!!!