# Command prompt within another widget

Tags: python

I have a GUI with label and entry widgets on a frame widget. I want to add a command prompt.to the frame through which the user can submit commands. I know about using the cmd module to create a prompt in the python shell, but I want the prompt to be part of my GUI window. Is there a way to 'embed' a command prompt in a canvas for example? Right now I am using Cmd.**init**(self) and cmdloop to start a prompt in python shell...

Just to clarify further, I would like the shell to run from within my GUI window (e.g. inside a canvas), and not as its own window. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, I am. You know how to solve my problem?

Comment: If you are using Linux, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253448/how-to-embed-a-terminal. If you are using Windows, you will have to use a similar method, but with a CMD window instead of an xterm one. I don't believe CMD has an `-into` property, so you'll have to tell the OS to put the CMD window inside of the Tkinter one, as opposed to having its own window. This means that you will need to have a very good understanding of the Windows API.

Answer (score 0):

The `cmd` module was made for terminals, where there's just one textual “widget” used for both input and output. This is not really suited for a GUI.

Here's an idea (inspired by web frameworks like Pyramid) that works better:

Have a read-only widget for the output, and a separate widget for the command entry.

When the user presses Enter, copy the command to the output box (prefixing with '>>>' and '...' as necessary), run the command (using `compile_command` and `run_code` from the [`code`](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) module, with redirecting `sys.stdout` to a `StringIO` that gets appended to the output), and then append the output in the output box.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try doing that, I'm quite new to python.