# Displaying the terminal in a tkinter GUI for Windows

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, terminal, xterm

I have been on a search for a way to embed/display the terminal output in a tkinter GUI, and the closest I have come to something that is I want to achieve is from the comments to the following question: ['xterm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964906)

Here they mention that it is possible to embed the a terminal window that runs the same process on Windows, but sadly they stop there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [build cmd into Tkinter window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999627/build-cmd-into-tkinter-window)

Comment: I wouldn't say so. It seems that the method provided there with the cmdtk, first of all is run in python2, and second of all does not appear to be completed work with the packages needed. 

It would seem that this is probably the closets I have come to an answer to the problem: [How to redirect print statements to Tkinter text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351786)

Comment: It's not specific and not clear. Do you want to render the standard output of the child process? Or do you want a terminal emulator like Putty?