# how to embed a vlc instance in a tkinter frame

Tags: python, tkinter, vlc

i wanna embed a vlc instance in a tkinter frame.
already there is a [similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7331836/9144712) here that show a terminal in a tkinter window
but i wanna show a vlc instead.
here is my vlc code:

```
import vlc
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('http://192.168.1.3:8080')
Media.add_option('network-caching=0')
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

and here is simple tkinter code

```
try:
    # Python2
     from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("380x480")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

frame1 = LabelFrame(root, width=459, height=300, bd=5)
frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
```

i want to show that vlc stream in this tkinter frame

Answer (score 1):

The VLC repo has a complete [example](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=examples/tkvlc.py;h=55314cab09948fc2b7c84f14a76c6d1a7cbba127;hb=HEAD) for Tkinter.

Comment: sorry, i saw this example before. but i couldn't handle it for myself

Answer (score 1):

With python-vlc, and vlc player installed (I had to intall the 32 bits version)

```
    self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
    self.player = self.Instance.media_player_new()
    self.player.set_hwnd(self.label.winfo_id())#tkinter label or frame

    media = self.Instance.media_new(f)
    self.player.set_media(media)
    self.player.play()
    sleep(1.5)

    duration = self.player.get_length() / 1000
    sleep(duration-1.5)
    self.player.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting the window I want the video to be played in with set_xwindow:

```
player.set_xwindow(display.winfo_id())
```

Another answer here uses **set_hwnd** which did not work for me (played only audio, while giving the same error of "no frame" etc.). When I exchanged it with **set_xwindow** it started to work and displayed the video as well as played the sound.

For vlc I ended up with:

```
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('example.mp4')
player.set_xwindow(display.winfo_id())
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

And for tkinter:

```
root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, width=700, height=600)
frame.pack()

display = tk.Frame(frame, bd=5)
display.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```