# Embed live console in a GUI frame with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, console, console-application

I am working on a GUI with tkinter. What I want to do is to embed a LIVE console in a tkinter frame. Can anyone help? I know that copying the content of the console and then writing it in the frame as text is a solution to display the content, but what I want to do is to display the LIVE content of the console.

Comment: No, you can't do this with tkinter.

Comment: Is it something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253448/how-to-embed-a-terminal-in-a-tkinter-application that you want to do? Are you talking about a system terminal or a python command line? Do you want it to be interactive (taking user input) or just redirect the output of your live console to your tkinter GUI?